# Has Gabriel Angelos worked with the Eldar?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I often hear that Gaberial Angelos has worked with the Eldar in the past. Not as momentary allies as is the norm for the wider Imperium but as a full-fledged ally and possible friendship. Is there cited lore to confirm this or mere rumor and theory like The Blood Ravens steal relics?

Comment: Heresy spread by xenos. Also, Eldars have no allies, only pawns.

Comment: @Yasskier, I believe the filthy xenos scum prefer the term, "Cats paw." And the Blood Ravens definitely steal relics.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Gabriel Angelos has been cooperating with Eldars on more than one occasion:

> Gabriel seems to have a mysterious bond with the Aeldari of the Biel-Tan Craftworld, particularly with Farseer Macha. Despite the condemnation and even threats from his fellow commanders, the Inquisition, the Adepta Sororitas and even from his own friend Isador Akios, Gabriel was stubborn in his attempts to assist the Aeldariand Macha on Tartarus. Surprisingly, the Harlequins of Arcadia refer to him as "Gabriel of the Hidden Heart," and see him as a symbol of hope for the Aeldari even though he is human.

HOWEVER, this information comes from books written by [C.S Goto](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/C.S._Goto), who is generally despised by fandom, because often he demonstrated lack of basic knowledge about the 40k universe. Case in point - the Biel-Tan are the most xenophobic and racist of the Craftworld Eldars, so it is highly doubtful that they would cooperate with a mere human.

In chronological order:

1. Angelos fights with Eldars on planet Tartarus: Eldars are trying to prevent the escape of a demon imprisoned on this world. Gabriel attempts to kill the demon, but instead he just breaks his containment. [Dawn of War I]
2. On Rahe's Paradise, Eldars keep killing Blood Raven recruits with psychic potentials to prevent destruction of Eldari artifact keeping Necrons dormant. Gabriel attempts to negotiate the truce, but the destruction of a Spirit Pool of the Dark Reaper Aspect managed to awake the Necrons [Goto]
3. Lorn V/Arcadia: Angelos is contacted by Farseer Taldeer and with a small squad goes through webway to Aeldari World of Law, known to the Imperium as Arcadia, where with the help of a troupe of Harlequins he finds a legendary Eldar sword Blade of Vaul. Gabriel gives this blade to Farseer Macha, who sacrifices herself to contain the Necron threat [Goto]
4. On Acheron, Gabriel Angelos, now the Chapter Master of Blood Ravens is again fighting against Eldari threat (Including Farseer Macha, who somehow survives her "sacrifice"), but in the end they team up against demon infestation.[DoW III]

The general rule in Wh40k universe is: Everything published is canon, but not everything is true. Take your pick.

On the other hand, the Blood <s>Magpies</s> Ravens [reputation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mabM64rAd4k&feature=youtu.be&t=14m13s) for "obtaining" relics might be well deserved if you look at the various artifacts that they have access to (in Dawn of War II they have access to relics from other chapters, even one that belonged to bloody Custodes!). But this can be explained in other way than stealing: as a fleet based chapter with support from the Empire, they might have to rely on scavenging the battlefields - something that the real ravens actually do.

One is true: they are indeed hoarding relics, many of which they they should not have as it belongs to other chapters -  please look at the official [Blood Ravens armory](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Blood_Ravens_Armoury):

- Axe of the Iron Snake (From the Iron Snakes chapter)
- Azrieel's second - sword from Dark Angels (a very secretive chapter itself)
- Bedlam Staff of Sinda Myrr (Alpha Legion)
- Doom of apostasy (a Dark Templar blade)
- Dorn's retribution (Iron Fist weapon)
- Fang of Fenris (Space Wolves)
- Holy Bolter of the Ancient (a **revered** relic from Ultramarines)

The list is long...

Comment: This could be a very good question but I don't think the links are appropriate: the first one seems to be a way to mock the misspellings in the OP, 1d4chan is just unsourced opinionated rant. I don't know the quality of the work of the Youtuber Eliphas, and I can't find any source in the description of his videos. People here seem to dislike wikis as they are written by "random persons on the internet", so I don't think the links here are useful.

Comment: @Taladris C.S. Goto IS a bad writer with a tendency to write torture porn (i.e. the description of mutilation of Taldeers body is waaay over the top even for 40k standards) and such poor grasp of the universe that makes people cringe: Eldars worshipping Slaanesh and kids disabling super-advanced tank using stick and stones are just top of the list. And multilasers. The reputation of Blood Ravens comes from the available equipment in the DOW II game, which kind of turned into a meme (example in the link)... which was semi-adopted by the fandom. Not sure what else can I explain

Comment: I don't know what "semi-accepted" could mean. And the notion of a unified fandom makes no sense (we are bordering the true Scotman fallacy here).

Comment: @Taladris now you are just catching on words. Is Lexicanum a more viable source for you? "Due to their origins in the Dawn of War games, as well as their **lore as relic-hoarders**, the Blood Ravens have an extensive list of relics and unique wargear. For the full list, please see Blood Ravens Armoury."  The mentioend armory has list of gear that Blood Ravens SHOULD NOT have (because it belongs to other chapters) https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Blood_Ravens_Armoury

Comment: Of course, Lexicanum is a more viable source since it supports its claims by reference to the source material. I don't like the tone of 1d4chan but my problem was the absence of sources. As I said, "I can't find any source in the description of [Eliphas'] videos". For example, from which books of Goto are the points 2 and 3 of your list are from? I don't contest Blood Ravens being relic-hoarders but who cares? That's not the point of the question and what needs to be sourced. And Goto being an awful writer or not does not matter on SE.

Comment: @Taladris it kind of matters, because his books make no sense from the lore or timeline perspective. Case in point - self sacrificing Farseer Macha is alive in DoW III after dying in Goto's book. Taldeer is alive and well after being mutilated etc. So while the books are canon, they are rather not true (and I chose them personally to be not true, because GW allows you to "pick your own truth")